# Show that whether or not the given random walk is mean ergodic.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, stochastic-calculus, random-walk

**GIVEN DATA:** For a Bernouilli stochastic process $X_i$, let’s define:

\begin{equation*}
Y_i=2X_i-1= \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & X_i=1  \\
            -1 &   X_i=0 \\
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

For each $n$,

$ S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{Y_i}$, $S_0=0$

**QUESTION:** Show that whether or not the given random walk is mean ergodic.

**MY WORKING:**

I know that the sequence of random variables $S_0,S_1,S_2,...$ is a one dimensional random walk.

Also, any process $X(t)$ is mean-ergodic if the time average estime converges to the ensemble average $\mu_X$ as $T\to \infty.$

I don't know how do I use the above information to reach the final resul which the question asks me to show. i.e: whether or not the random walk is mean ergodic.

Does anyone have any **idea** how do I show it? Any **guidance** will be appreciated.

**Thanks.**

Comment: Mean-sense ergodicity is typically defined only for processes that are stationary, at least in the wide sense. The process $\ S_n\ $ isn't stationary, however, not even in the wide sense. While the definition of mean-ergodicity might be extended to apply to the case when just the mean of $\ S_n\ $ is stationary, even that isn't true unless the Bernoulli process $\ X_i\ $ is unbiassed. Are you sure your statement of the question is correct?

Comment: @lonzaleggiera the statement is correct. If mean-sense ergodicity is defined only for stationary processes, and you say that given $S_n$ isn't stationary which means Given $S_n$ isn't mean ergodic. The question is how do I show tha given $S_n$ isn't stationary?

Comment: If $\ X_i $ is biassed with $\ \mathbb{P}\big(X_i\big)=p\ne\frac{1}{2}\ $ then $\ \mathbb{E}\big(S_n\big)=$$\,n(2p-1)\ $, which isn't independent of $\ n\ $, so $\ S_n\ $ isn't wide-sense stationary in this case. I was wrong about the unbiassed case, however, because I miscalculated the autocovariance, $\ \mathbb{Cov}\big(S_n,S_{n+r}\big)\ $, for which I'm now getting $\ 4np(1-p)=n\ $. Since this is independent of $\ r\ $, $\ S_n\ $ *is* wide-sense stationary in this case.   Apologies for the error.

Comment: To decide on mean ergodicity in this case, therefore, you'll have to calculate the appropriate limits and check whether they satisfy the required conditions.

Comment: As for as I know random walks are neither WSS nor SSS. How $S_n$ is wide-sense stationary here, since $S_n$ is random walk so It shouldn't be WSS.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera kindly provide calculations for ergodicity as well. I am unable to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment about the wide-sense stationarity of $\ S_n\ $ I confused the two indices.  For $\ S_n\ $ to be wide-sense stationary, the autocovariance, $\ \mathbb{Cov}\big(S_nS_{n+r}\big)\ $, must be a function of $\ r\ $ alone, independent of $\ n\ $.

Let
$$
p=\mathbb{P}\big(X_i=1\big)\ .
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(Y_i\big)&=2p-1\ \text{, and}\\
\mathbb{Cov}\big(Y_i,Y_j\big)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\big(Y_i-(2p-1)\big)\big(Y_j-(2p-1)\big)\right)\\
&=4p(1-p)\delta_{ij}\ .
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{Cov}\big(S_nS_{n+r}\big)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+r}\left(\big(Y_i-(2p-1)\big)\big(Y_j-(2p-1)\big)\right)\right)\\
&=4p(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n+r}\delta_{ij}\\
&=4p(1-p)\sum_{i=1}^n1\\
&=4p(1-p)n\ .
\end{align}
Since this is not independent of $\ n\ $, then $\ S_n\ $ is not wide-sense stationary, and the definition of mean ergodicity isn't applicable to it